# Struggling to create drop down menu on side bar in html

Tags: php, html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a side menu and I have a lot of menu item so I would like to include drop down menus to group them. while it is almost working I need a way for it to expand and contract when the property menu is clicked on to reveal or hide the sub menu

This is my code

```
<li class="sub-menu dcjq-parent-li">
            <a class="dcjq-parent active" href="javascript:;">
              <i class="fa fa-desktop"></i>
              <span>Properties</span>
              <span class="dcjq-icon"></span></a>
            <ul class="sub" style="display: block;">
              <li><a href="manage.php">Manage</a></li>
              <li class="active"><a href="add.php">Add</a></li>
              
            </ul>
          </li>
```

This appears correctly but when the user clicks on properties I would like it to either open or close the sub menu.
Could someone help me with this please

Comment: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/components/dropdowns/

Comment: Do oyu have any **specific** question about this? How is this problem related to PHP?

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown();
});
```

'''add this script in your code'''

Comment: sorry this does nothing and is not what I am after

Comment: This answer is only a small part of the solution, the html needs some things for this script to hook into.